# Using Datumbox in Python for Sentiment Analysis

Tags: python, module, wrapper, sentiment-analysis, datumbox

as I am relatively new to Python Programming I am not sure how to use Datumbox in a code properly. I need it to perform some sentiment analysis, however, I am not able to implement it by conda/pip install DatumBox as I would normally do!

The following stuff is available on github. DatumBox seems to be offered in many different programming languages but has no big community in Python so far:

https://github.com/Lily418/Datumbox-Python-Wrapper

How do I have to use the material from the link to use DatumBox as a module in Python? I already have an API KEY and now I want to implement it in my code import DatumBox etc.....

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this wrapper: https://github.com/irish315/Datumbox-Python-Wrapper

```
$ git clone git@github.com:irish315/Datumbox-Python-Wrapper.git
$ cd Datumbox-Python-Wrapper
$ python
>>> from DatumBox import DatumBox
>>> datum_box = DatumBox(API_KEY)
>>> datum_box.twitter_sentiment_analysis("I love my cat")
u'positive'
```